# Virtual environments not working on pycharm and jupyterN

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, virtual-environment

I had to uninstall anaconda,

and since then I am not able to import NumPy or any other library since virtual environments are not working correctly anymore 
getting this err:

```
'''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d4cdadb62aa7> in <module>

----> 1 import numpy

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138 
    139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
    142     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:
'''
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

how to uninstall anaconda the environment which had that library disappeared, just try to install that library normally and that's it.

Comment: seems like there is two paths to the same library